# SQL Azure SPLIT ON UNIQUEIDENTIFIER GUID

Tags: sql, asp.net-membership, azure-sql-database

Let's say there is an application generating random GUIDs corresponding to number of normalized records in a few tables. These records with GUID "tenant_id" need to be split into multiple federated members in SQL Azure. When the SPLIT AT command is issued, what ordering mechanism is used to split members at a specific point (tenant_id)? Is it similar to ORDER BY GUID_FIELD ASC/DESC resultset? Since GUIDs are generated randomly, what is the best way to create ranges with future splits?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUIDs ranges are split according to their sort order in SQL Server - the same that is used for ORDER BY and indexes. See this blog post for more details on this: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2007/08/31/how-are-guids-sorted-by-sql-server.aspx

If you are generating GUIDs randomly and you need to split, you should use the ordering definition for GUIDs to pick a point somewhere in the middle of the set of GUIDs in the member you are splitting (assuming you want to split in the middle).

If you want more control about what tenants go where, you could generate your own, "custom" GUIDs, but then you will of course lose the global uniqueness property that GUIDs have, unless you ensure globally unique generation of your "custom" GUIDs.

-- Hans Olav

Comment: You're correct. But consider what happens after the federations are splitted. You may insert more and more data. GUIDs are automatically generated. You have no control. So there's still a risk that most of those new data will be inserted into a single federation. The risk can be reduced, but not eliminated, if you split the federation in the middle. I'm not saying GUID cannot be used as federation key. Just point out a potential risk.

Comment: Microsoft Membership provider is using GUIDs for userId and I do not want to modify membership tables to use a non-guid based data types unless there is an inexpensive way to introduce a mechanism generating new IDs on different servers (App Servers) that are unique.

Comment: @MingXu-MSFT, having your data balanced when using GUIDs and splitting in the middle is a matter of statistics. You will have to consider that value ranges ranges are huge and the generated values are totally random. If you are only generating 3 values, then indeed there are slight chances that all 3 might end up in one federation, but if you are generating 1000 values, statistically speaking they will be distributed in a roughly balanced way.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, split at splits a single federation into two. It relies on the distribution key (the key you passed in the federated on clause). For example, imagine you federate on age. Origianlly you have two federations: age from 0 to 40, and age from 41 to 80. Now you split the first federation into two parts: 0 to 20 and 21 to 40. SQL Azure will automatically organize the data to make sure each federation meets the range requirement. So yes, it is kind of like order by.

Usually federation is not used on GUIDs. Instead, it's used on some key that you have more control. Using GUID is fine, but you have the risk to unbalance the federations. One federation may contain a lot of data, while the other only a little.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a GUID as the federation key. You can split to ensure balanced size/load for every federation member.

Comment: The major part of the question asked about ordering of GUIDs. If I split at some_guid E(belongs) some federated member then I need to know how many AU will go to a new member 1 and member 2. Or, to put in other way, what is the best way to find a midpoint GUID in a range? What GUID ordering mechanism is used?

Comment: You don't have to worry about how SQL Azure sorts GUID internally. To find the mid point of existing data, you can sort all data by GUID (use orderby). Count the data, and find the middle item's GUID.