# SQL Azure and Membership Provider Tenant ID

Tags: asp.net-membership, azure-sql-database

What might be a good way to introduce BIGINT into the ASP.NET Membership functionality to reference users uniquely and to use that BIGINT field as a tenant_id? It would be perfect to keep the existing functionality generating UserIds in the form of GUIDs and not to implement a  membership provider from ground zero. Since application will be running on multiple servers, the BIGINT tenant_id must be unique and it should not depend on some central authority generating these IDs. It will be easy to use these tenant_id with a SPLIT AT command down the road which will allow bucketing users into new federated members. Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bigint. But you may have to modify all stored procedures that rely on user ID. Making ID global unique is usually not a problem. As long as the ID is the primary key, database will force it to be unique. Otherwise you will get errors when inserting new data (in that case, you can modify ID and retry).

So the most important difference is you may need to modify stored procedures. You have a choice here. If you use GUID, you don't need to do anything. But it may be difficult to predict how to split the federation to balance queries. As pointed out in another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885768/sql-azure-split-on-uniqueidentifier-guid/10890552#comment14211028_10890552), you can sort existing data at the mid point. But you don't know future data will be inserted in which federation. There's a potential risk that federations will become unbalanced, and you may need to merge and split them at a regular interval to keep them in shape.

By using bigint, you have better control over the key. For example, you have two federations. The first has ID from 1 to 10000, and the second has ID from 10001 to 20000. When creating a new user, you first check how many records are in each federation. Suppose federation 1 has 500 records and federation 2 has 1000 records, to balance the load, you choose to insert to federation 1, so you choose an ID between 1 and 10000. But using bigint, you may need to do more work to modify stored procedures.